# Parent folder permissions for subfolder read/write access

Tags: active-directory

Using active directory, I want a specific user to only have read/write access to a specific sub-folder of a parent folder.

What permissions does that user need on the parent folder?

Answer (score 0):

You will need read/execute permission on the parent folder and read/write/execute on the child. For example:

```
$ mkdir -p foo/bar
$ chmod 755 foo/
$ chmod 777 hoo/ko
```